# Trying to understand a proof in Rudin concerning winding number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

In the proof of theorem 10.10 in Real and complex analysis Rudin states that if we will differentiate
$$\phi(t) = \exp \left\{\int_a^t \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)-z} \,\textrm{d}s\right\}, \textrm{we obtain the equality: } \frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)} = \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-z} $$ which is true almost everywhere (with exception of set $S$, which is finite: $\gamma$ doesn't have to have the derivative everywhere). I can understand this:
$$\ln \phi(t) = \int_a^t \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)-z} \,\textrm{d}s \textrm{ implies } (\ln \phi(t))' = \frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)} = \dots = \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t) - z}.$$
I hope that the preceeding reasoning is correct (if not, what to do?). But how to conclude that $\phi / (\gamma -z )$ is a continuous function on $[a, b]$ whose derivative is zero on $[a,b] \setminus S$? Here $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb C$ is a closed path. Especially the derivative part is a trouble. Of course, it is true that
$$\frac{\phi(t)}{\gamma(t)-z} = \frac{\phi'(t)}{\gamma'(t)}.$$
If RHS is constant, then $\phi'(t) = c \gamma'(t)$.
Using the definition I write
$$\phi'(t) = \exp \left\{\int_a^t \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)-z} \,\textrm{d}s\right\} \cdot \frac{1}{\gamma(t)-z} \cdot \gamma'(t) = c(t) \cdot \gamma'(t).$$
Looking at this I'm not convinced that $c$ is $t$-independent (constant).

Comment: In English, the word "become" doesn't mean anything like the German word "bekommen", so it doesn't make sense to say "we become the equality". Probably something like "we obtain the equality" is what you meant. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is quite obvious. We know that $\phi(t) \gamma'(t) = \phi'(t) (\gamma(t)-z)$, so:
$$\left[\frac {\phi(t)}{\gamma(t)-z}\right]' = \frac{\phi'(t)(\gamma(t)-z) - \phi (t) \gamma'(t)}{(\gamma(t)-z)^2} = 0.$$

I will leave it here, maybe somebody will find it helpful.